# undefined reference to something I have defined

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

So I am completely stumped. I am getting an error `undefined reference to Transition::Transition()` which is the default constructor for one of my classes, but I swear I'm doing everything correctly. Here's whats going on in my driver.cpp

```
...other includes and namespace std
#include"state.h"
#include"transition.h"

int main(...){
    vector<State> stateVect;
    vector<Transition> transVect;
    State state;
    Transition transition;
}
```

So I KNOW that I am correctly linking my files, because I am not getting any errors for vector itself, its just the `Transition transition` causing me problems. But here's the kicker, my `State state` works just fine and its the same thing as my `Transition transition` basically.

Here is my full transition.h

```
#ifndef TRANSITION_H
#define TRANSITION_H

#include<string>

class Transition{
    public: 
//I know these all shouldn't be public, but that's not the point right now
        int q;
        string a; 
        int r; 
        string b; 
        string x; 

        Transition();
        Transition(int q, string a, int r, string b, string x);
        int getq();
        string geta();
        int getr();
        string getb();
        string getx();
};
#endif // TRANSITION_H
```

and here is my transition.cpp

```
using namespace std;

#include"transition.h"

//here it is!!!!!
Transition::Transition(){

}

//this is also somehow undefined
Transition::Transition(int qIn, string aIn, int rIn, string bIn, string xIn){
    q = qIn;
    a = aIn;
    r = rIn;
    b = bIn;
    x = xIn;
}

int Transition::getq(){
    return q;
}

string Transition::geta(){
    return a;
}

int Transition::getr(){
    return r;
}

string Transition::getb(){
    return b;
}

string Transition::getx(){
    return x;
}
```

Clearly I have defined a reference to Transition::Transition() (as well as the other constructor that's the one I was originally trying to get to work, but when I found that didn't work for some reason I just tried going with the default constructor). For comparison, here is my state.h and state.cpp which work.

state.h

```
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H

class State{
    public:
        int stateNum; //0 - 1,000
        bool isAccept;
        bool isReject;
        bool isStart; //can be also reject XOR accept

        State();
        State(int stateNum, bool isAccept, bool isReject, bool isStart);
        State& operator= (const State s);
        int getNum();
        void setAccept();
        void setReject();
        void setStart();
};
#endif //STATE_H
```

and state.cpp

```
using namespace std;

#include"state.h"

//works 
State::State(){

}

//also works
State::State(int stateNumIn, bool isAcceptIn, bool isRejectIn, bool isStartIn){
    stateNum = stateNumIn;
    isAccept = isAcceptIn;
    isReject = isRejectIn;
    isStart = isStartIn;
}

State& State::operator= (const State s){
    stateNum = s.stateNum;
    isAccept = s.isAccept;
    isReject = s.isReject;
    isStart = s.isStart;
    return *this;
}

int State::getNum(){
    return stateNum;
}

void State::setAccept(){
    isAccept = true;
}

void State::setReject(){
    isReject = true;
}

void State::setStart(){
    isStart = true;
}
```

I have no idea why both constructors work for State, but neither work for Transition. I've been looking at these files for half an hour and I see nothing wrong. Can anyone spot my error? Like I said, driver.cpp definitely knows about Transition, since vector throws no errors, its when I add the line `Transition transition` that it tells me I have a reference to something undefined. Same thing if I try to value constructor of Transition.

Comment: Are you linking `Transition.o` to your executable actually?

Comment: To make questions easier for others to read and answer, you should delete all unnecessary code. All the data members and member functions are irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: `using namespace std;` should come *after* including your header (and your header should write `std::string` specifically). Otherwise you risk introducing silent ODR violations because tokens in the header get looked up differently by different units.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ BINGO I looked at my makefile for like 2 minutes I can't believe I didn't catch that, thanks